# Error installing any npm

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I receive this error when installing any npm:

> 30 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
>   31 error argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "npm" "-g"
>   32 error node v0.12.7
>   33 error npm  v2.11.3
>   34 error code ECONNREFUSED
>   35 error errno ECONNREFUSED
>   36 error syscall connect
>   37 error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11) at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1010:19)
>   37 error  { [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
>   37 error   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
>   37 error   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
>   37 error   syscall: 'connect' }
>   38 error If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
>   38 error 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
>   39 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Can you give me any help?

Comment: And are you behind a proxy? (If not, are you sure? Have you checked with your network administrator?)

Comment: Yes? So did you check that the proxy config was set correctly? Did you read npm help config?

Comment: it's first time im doing it so may be there is a problem in the configuration 
any way this is form .npmrc file
proxy=http://domainname:8080
htps-proxy=http://domainname:8080
https-proxy=http://domainname:8080

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm ERR! Error: connect ECONNREFUSED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42371380/npm-err-error-connect-econnrefused)

Answer (score 2):

You should `set proxy` for `npm config` first. Please refer to the article below. Hope it will help.

> https://jjasonclark.com/how-to-setup-node-behind-web-proxy

Answer (score 1):

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
```

Set the proxies like above and it will work fine

mention your organisation name in company or your organisation's proxy address with port