# npm ERR! Error: connect ECONNREFUSED when trying to update the npm

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I'm trying to update the npm (node package manager) using the command:

> npm install npm@latest -g

but I'm getting the following error in the command prompt:

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "npm@latest" "-g"

npm ERR! node v6.9.5
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! errno ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! syscall connect

npm ERR! Error: connect ECONNREFUSED xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxx
npm ERR!     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
npm ERR! If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
```

does someone know what this really means?
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you sit behind a proxy?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the npm ERR! 'proxy' config is set properly. See: 'npm help config'

See:

- https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/config

More info:

- [How to setup Node.js and Npm behind a corporate web proxy](https://jjasonclark.com/how-to-setup-node-behind-web-proxy/)

Comment: This actually worked. I ran these 2 commands and after that I could Install the packages.   npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
                        npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080

Comment: npm help config does nothing

Answer (score 77):

Try:

```
npm config set proxy null
npm config set https-proxy null
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

The first two lines will remove proxy's if there any.

Third line will make `npm` download from the official package registry.

Comment: Please add a bit of explanation. This answer has been flagged for being too short.

Comment: I've tried removing the proxy but it didn't work, setting them to null fixed the issue :/

Answer (score 4):

I got a similar error when I was using Node JS behind a proxy server. Here's what I had to do to fix it:

```
npm config set proxy http://jdoe:password123@proxy.company.com:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://jdoe:password123@proxy.company.com:8080
```

Just replace "jdoe" and "password123" with your own credentials to access the proxy server. Everything after the @ is the server domain name, or you can enter the exact IP address too. In my case, both addresses were HTTP (not HTTPS).

To confirm the changes, you can type:

```
npm config list
```

and your settings should be listed.

You can get the proxy settings (address) from your browser too.

Answer (score 4):

I have been trying to fix this issue by

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
npm config set proxy http://myproxyblabla:myport
npm config set https-proxy http://myproxyblabla:myport
```

But it didn't help. The only one solution which **worked for me** is adding additional fields to host file (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts)

```
151.101.36.162 registry.npmjs.com
151.101.36.162 registry.npmjs.org
```

This allowes npm to resolve address to server from which it will download needed files.
You can get familiar with **[closed issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/13284)** on npm repository where this solution is approved by npm contributors.

Comment: cool, its working.

npm config set proxy http://myproxyblabla:myport
npm config set https-proxy http://myproxyblabla:myport

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is because of proxy. So you need to run the below-mentioned command to remove the proxy and then set the registry from http://registry.npmjs.org/.

```
    npm config set proxy null
    npm config set https-proxy null
    npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

And then you can create your first react app by using:

```
    npx create-react-app your-app-name
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error, using Mullvad VPN. It was fixed by enabling IPv6 in Mullvad settings.

Answer (score 2):

May be this will help someone in need. I turned to this solution after wasting good 2 hours as my corporate proxy server on work laptop was not getting resolved..!

I removed both `proxy` and `https-proxy` from **`.npmrc`** file and set only

`npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/`

Then, I am able to successfully run `npm install -g create-react-app`

**`.npmrc`** file can be found here at **`C:\Users\<userName>\.npmrc`**

Cheers! *Happy Quarantine Development* :p

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my `cra` and all I had to do was comment out my `.npmrc`,  clean the cache, and run the command `npx create-react-app`

Answer (score 0):

We faced similar issue recently and our requirement was to use public npm registry for one feature and private registry for another feature. So for private registry npm needs to go via proxy but for public registry we don't need proxy so we created `.npmrc` file inside our project and added two config variables:

`registry` and `noproxy` where `noproxy` points to the public domain of the registry. This will make sure to skip the proxy config from your global npmrc file.

Answer (score -1):

We happened to run into this error message because in our setup, the Maven Nexus NPM Repository ran on the same machine and we therefore first used `http://localhost/xyz/` as the NPM repository URL.

For whatever reason, `localhost` was treated as a system-type NPM registry, causing errors.

Changing the NPM repository URL configuration to the computer's hostname, e.g. `http://mycomputer.company.intra/xyz/` fixed the issue.

Answer (score -2):

What fixed it for me, was to enable SMB 1.0 in Window's Control Panel on my development PC as follows:

Control Panel > Programs and Features > Turn Windows features on or off > SMB 1.0

[image]