# Npm install always return `code ECONNREFUSED` error for all packages

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

```
`npm ERR! code ECONNREFUSED
 npm ERR! errno ECONNREFUSED
 npm ERR! FetchError: request to http://registry.npmjs.org/body-parser failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000`
```

I tried `proxy settings` ,`registry set commands`..But still no use..

Im using node js latest version..and my app listen port is `3000`

I tried `npm config List`..is there any wrong configuration?

```
 `; cli configs
 metrics-registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
  scope = ""
 user-agent = "npm/5.3.0 node/v8.1.4 win32 ia32"

; userconfig C:\Users\JANEN\.npmrc
https-proxy = "http://proxy.company.com:8080/"
proxy = "http://proxy.company.com:8080/"
registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"

; builtin config undefined
prefix = "C:\\Users\\JANEN\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm"

 ; node bin location = C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe
; cwd = C:\project\authenticationIntro-master
; HOME = C:\Users\JANEN
; "npm config ls -l" to show all defaults.
```

`

Comment: Check your `hosts` file: `$ cat /private/etc/hosts`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm ERR! Error: connect ECONNREFUSED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42371380/npm-err-error-connect-econnrefused)

Comment: @Maxim  can you text me the exact path `cat /private/etc/hosts`??

Comment: @Maximo  I tried those things..Still geting same error..

Comment: Please see my updated question

Answer (score 0):

If you're behind a company proxy, the connection is probably refused because the user authentication fails.

Change the proxy address to `"http://username:password@proxy.company.com:port"`

This should hopefully solve your problem.