# Not able to install `@angular/cli` in windows using VPN connect

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am trying to install the `@angular/cli` using npm, but getting error as below. I a in client place where i use the vpn connect.

[image: error]

Comment: Why down vote..? what is wrong here

Comment: I guess you are behind a proxy you need to configure it  see [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-use-npm-install-the-command-behind-corporate-proxy-server/)

Answer (score 0):

According your log. I think this issue is similar with ([npm ERR! Error: connect ECONNREFUSED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42371380/npm-err-error-connect-econnrefused?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)). And
You should config your NPM proxy properly.

I think below command may help you.

`npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/` // Set your registry to npm instead of local

`npm config set http-proxy http://username:password@ip:port` // Config your http_proxy

`npm config set https-proxy http://username:password@ip:port` // Config your https_proxy