# Error: Econnrefused during React Native Installation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, npm-install, create-react-native-app

I've tried to install reactive native from the link https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html on my personal Mac book. It is resulting in below error. I've Xcode installed in my machine but don't know nothing much about the proxy configuration in this error. 
[image]

Comment: Well, the last two lines asks if you are behind a proxy... are you on a work network? Seems like a network issue? Try it on your home network?

Comment: Hi cheriejw, I found the solution for this problem by setting the proxy configuration to null from this question in stack over flow. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42371380/npm-err-error-connect-econnrefused