# npm install not working in laravel 10.21.0

Tags: laravel, npm, installation

[This is a screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZPOL.png)

laravel 10.21.0

here i am trying to install laravel breeze package. breeze package installed without any issue. but when i refresh register and login page , there are a error massage. that massage advised to install npm.

**edit**
node -v = v18.17.1
npm -v = 9.6.7

Comment: What is the version of your node and npm? do both `node -v` and `npm -v`

Comment: I cant see the end of the error. Just to clarify but does the computer you are trying to install packages from can connect to the internet?

Comment: Did you check any other SO questions with the same issue? If you checked your error you get `ECONNREFUSED`

Comment: Try to do the solutions found in this SO: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42371380

Comment: Another possibility is that the network you are on refuses to connect to the node registry thus unable to download the necessary packages.

Comment: Thank you for support me. i solved the problem. here, first i need to run npm update and npm run dev.  there problem occurred on my proxy connection. I disconnect with proxy and run commands again.  its working now. **thank you again all of you**

Answer (score -1):

As you mentioned there is an error message. that message advised to install npm, then there is a missing node in your machine. First of all, check your node via the command

```
node --version
```

If you see there is a version of node then you can now run

```
npm install
```

If you don't see any version then you have to download the node installer file from the [link](https://nodejs.org/en/download)

After installing the node, check the node version and install the node module in your project.

Answer (score -1):

install the javascript modules using the following command

```
npm install
```

or

```
npm i
```

If npm is installed, try the following command

```
npm update
```